# how a program maps onto a computer's memory and operations?

Tags: c++, c, memory-management, compiler-construction

What writes compiler for functions and does it allocate memory for it ?and how?
Generally it is easy to visualize that data structures are stored in memory. But how OPERATIONS? like statements in a function body? what compiler does for them?

Comment: I know you guys are brainy. But still if you do not have time to help on this question please do not underestimate. A simple question for you might be still hard for other. Thanks

Comment: The reason your question is closed is that it's not a PRECISE question - it requires more or less a book to answer this. There are books suggested in your previous question that was almost identical. Don't expect people here to not spot that you're asking an identical question!

Comment: I have refereed to most of the books on this subject , but sometime they confused more! then look help from forums. This happened to me, that why I was asking this question.

Comment: Yes, you may find better forums than SO for this type of question, since it's a lengthy subject that isn't easily explained. Or ask a more specific question, rather than asking a question that is a 200 page book as an answer. It's unlikely anyone here will write a 200 page book answer.

Comment: It make sense. Many thanks for your info. So should I need to delete this question then to help forum?

Comment: No need to delete it. The point is that you learn how to ask appropriate questions for the appropriate answerers. SO's purpose is for fairly direct questions that can be answered in about a page or two worth of text. It can be hard to know when you ask. That's why there is a system for voting to close questions for various reasons. There are many thousands of closed questions. Someone may well search for this subject and find the information in the discussion useful, even if it doesn't provide a complete answer.

Answer (score 2):

Operations are the steps you need to make something work. Say you have the following code fragment:

```
int a = 1;
int b = 2;
int c = a + b;
```

This will involve some storage for `a`, `b` and `c`, and some sort of operations to store the values `1` into `a`, the value `2` into `b`, and then to calculate `a+b` and store that into `c`.

Understanding how this works is key to understanding how computers work in general, and it's quite a complex subject to cover completely, and I doubt it's suitable as a simple question here.

Comment: so compiler generate these instructions and when program load does memory store these? this is the confusion , how instruction could store like data?

Comment: Yes, instructions are stored in memory. In most (modern) systems, instructions and data are stored in the same memory, just at different locations. In older systems, "code" was sometimes separate memory to "data" in various ways.

Comment: Many thanks for this reply . So then CPU how would distinguish whether its data or instructions?

Comment: Typically, by the program being started with instructions, and instructions only lead onto other instructions. But if you write code that somehow end up "jumping" to data, then the processor will interpret that data as instructions, and keep going as long as it's forming valid instructions. The operating system may prevent this by setting different regions of memory as "don't execute this", but not all processors and OS's support that.